# Trying to calculate and print statement the total sum of 3 different Times

Tags: java, arrays, string, testing, time

I am trying to modify the main method in the Relay class so that in addition to printing the various times, it also prints their sum (the sum of all 3 times). Because they are a string, i'm not sure where the math can be done. Along with this I also am trying to change the array in the Relay class so that it holds Time objects rather than TimeA objects. Thanks!

```
        //Relay.java
            public class Relay 
            {
              public static void main(String[] args) 
                {
                   TimeA[] raceLegs = new TimeA[3];
                   raceLegs[0] = new TimeA(903);
                   raceLegs[1] = new TimeA(0,1,43);
                   raceLegs[2] = new TimeA(0,45,17);

                   System.out.println("First runner:  " + raceLegs[0].toString());
                   System.out.println("Second runner: " + raceLegs[1].toString());
                   System.out.println("Third runner:  " + raceLegs[2].toString());

        //my clearly wrong attempt 
         System.out.println("The sum of all the runners is:  " + 
         raceLegs[0].toString() + raceLegs[1].toString()+ raceLegs[2].toString());
                }      
            }       

    //TimeATestToString.java

      public class TimeATestToString {

        @Test
        public void testClassic() {
            Time t = new TimeA(23,15,54);
            assertEquals("23:15:54", t.toString());
        }

        @Test
        public void testSingleDigits() {
            Time t = new TimeA(1,2,3);
            assertEquals("1:02:03", t.toString());
        }

        @Test
        public void testZeros() {
            Time t = new TimeA(1,3,0);
            assertEquals("1:03:00", t.toString());
        }
        @Test
        public void testZeros2() {
            Time t = new TimeA(12,0,0);
            assertEquals("12:00:00", t.toString());
        }
    }  
//TimeA.java
public class TimeA implements Time
{

    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;

    /**
     * Simple constructor assumes data is in proper format
     * @param h number of hours
     * @param m number of minutes
     * @param s number of seconds
     */
    public TimeA(int h, int m, int s) 
    {
        hours = h;
        minutes = m;
        seconds = s;
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover seconds (those not part of a full minute) 
     *      in this object
     * @return the number of seconds
     */
   public int getSeconds()
   {
       return seconds;
   }
   /**
    * Return the number of leftover minutes (those not part of a full hour) 
    *       in this object
    * @return the number of minutes
    */
   public int getMinutes()
   {
       return minutes;
   }

   /**
    * Return the number of full hours in this object
    * @return the number of hours
    */
   public int getHours()
   {
       return hours;
   }


    /**
     * Constructor that assumes a total number of seconds
     * @param total the total number of seconds taken
     */   
    public TimeA(int total) 
    {
        hours = total/3600;
        minutes = (total/60) % 60;
        seconds = total % 60;
    }


    /**
     * Adds the given time to the current time, producing the sum
     * @param other the given time to add
     * @return the sum of this time and the other time
     */
//    public Time add (Time other) 
//    {
//        return new TimeA(1,2,3);
//    }
    public Time add (Time other) 
    {
        int remainder = 0;
        int newSec = this.seconds + other.getSeconds();

        // if over a minute, carry.
        if (newSec >= 60) {
           remainder = 1;
           newSec -= 60;
        }
        this.seconds = newSec;
        int newMin = this.minutes + remainder + other.getMinutes();
        remainder = 0;

        // carry if over an hour
        if (newMin >= 60) {
            remainder = 1;
            newMin -= 60;
        }
        this.minutes = newMin;
        this.hours += other.getHours() + remainder;

        return this;
    }
    /**
     * Return a String representation of this time
     * @return this time represented as a String in hh:mm:ss format
     */
    public String toString() 
    {
         return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

        // return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    } 

    public int compareTo(Time other) { 
        return 17;
    }
}
//TimeATestAdd.java
public class TimeATestAdd {

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        Time t = new TimeA(0,44,19);
        Time s = new TimeA(0,17,44);
        Time u = s.add(t);
        assertEquals("1:02:03", u.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        Time t = new TimeA(4,19,21);
        Time s = new TimeA(2,40,18);
        Time u = s.add(t);
        assertEquals("6:59:39", u.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void thirdTest() {
        Time t = new TimeA(2,19,45);
        Time s = new TimeA(2,40,5);
        Time u = s.add(t);
        assertEquals("4:59:50", u.toString());
    }
    @Test
    public void fourthTest() {
        Time t = new TimeA(9,12,15);
        Time s = new TimeA(2,20,5);
        Time u = s.add(t);
        assertEquals("11:32:20", u.toString());
    }
}
//Time.java
public interface Time extends Comparable<Time> {

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover seconds (those not part of a full minute) 
     *      in this object
     * @return the number of seconds
     */
    public int getSeconds();

    /**
     * Return the number of leftover minutes (those not part of a full hour) 
     *      in this object
     * @return the number of minutes
     */
    public int getMinutes();

    /**
     * Return the number of full hours in this object
     * @return the number of hours
     */
    public int getHours();

    /**
     * Return a String representation of this object in hh:mm:ss format
     * @return this object as a String 
     */
    public String toString();

    /**
     * Add the given time record to this one
     * @param other the time record to be added to this one
     * @return the sum of this time record and the other
     */
    public Time add(Time other);

}
```

Comment: So you already have an `add(Time)` method? What is the question then? How to make a sum "a + b + c" using only +?

Comment: Yes their are print statements inside Relay.java and I am trying to modify the main method to add and print their sum. But aside from that I am trying to change the array in the Relay class so that it holds Time objects rather than TimeA objects. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` method of objects always returns a `String`, but you evidently put integers into the objects of `TimeA`, so that is where you can do the addition. Without knowing what that class looks like, my best guess is:

```
class TimeA implements Time {

    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;

    public TimeA(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public void addTime(TimeA other) {
        this.hours += other.hours;
        this.minutes += other.minutes;
        this.seconds += other.seconds;
    }
}
```

So how do you sum these values? How would you do it without programming? Let's say you have "5 + 7 + 9", you'd take 5, add 7, then 9, then you'd have a result. So that's what you want to do now, too:

```
 raceLegs[0].add( raceLegs[1] );
 raceLegs[0].add( raceLegs[2] );

 System.out.println("Sum:  " + raceLegs[0].toString());
```

*(I'm not sure what you mean with "I also am trying to change the array in the Relay class so that it holds Time objects", but it might be as easy as changing `TimeA[] raceLegs = new TimeA[3]` to `Time[] raceLegs = new Time[3]`.)*

Comment: Thank you soo so much. I appreciate it greatly